# Tweepy streaming tweets into azure cosmosdb

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, azure-cosmosdb, tweepy

how do i add tweepy streaming data into an existing azure cosmosdb database?
my script ends up with an argument of type 'int' is not iterable error.

Is there an other way to write real-time tweets to cosmosdb using python?

I have looked on microsofts documentation but i can't figure out what i need to change to make it work

```
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

search_terms = ["#weer", "#regen", "#zon", "#wind", "#neerslag", "#sneeuw", "#onweer", "#droog","Schiphol"]

testtweet= None

class MyStream(tweepy.StreamingClient):


    # This function gets called when the stream is working
    def on_connect(self):

        print("Connected")

    # This function gets called when a tweet passes the stream
    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        global testtweet
        global lijst2
        lijst2 = {}
        testtweet = tweet
        # Displaying tweet in console
        if tweet.referenced_tweets == None:
            print(tweet.data)
            lijst2[testtweet.id] = testtweet.text
            try:
                tweet.data['entities']['urls'][0]['images']
            except KeyError:
                present = False
            else:
                present = True

            if present:
                for x in testtweet.data['entities']['urls'][0]['images']:
                    response = requests.get(testtweet.data['entities']['urls'][0]['images'][0]['url'])
                    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
                    plt.imshow(img)
                    plt.show()
            #client.like(tweet.id)

            # Delay between tweets
        lijst3 = lijst2
        print(lijst3)
        time.sleep(0.5)

        url = config.settings['host']
        key = config.settings['master_key']

        DATABASE_ID = config.settings['database_id']
        CONTAINER_ID = config.settings['container_id']

        client = CosmosClient(url, credential=key)
        database_name = 'tweepy'
        database = client.get_database_client(database_name)
        container_name = 'tweepy'
        container = database.get_container_client(container_name)


        #does not work
        for i in lijst3:
            container.upsert_item(i)



# Creating Stream object
stream = MyStream(bearer_token=bearer_token)

for term in search_terms:
    stream.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule(term))


# Starting stream
stream.filter(tweet_fields=["referenced_tweets",'author_id','created_at','entities'])
```

Comment: Your upsert code is pushing empty documents, with no id or any other properties.

Comment: Ok - I see you edited your upsert call. Can you please show an example or two of what `lijst3` contains, since that's the call that's not working?